# Can `BUFFER-COMPARE` receive fields to compare dynamically?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

When trying to dynamically set the `USING` fields of BUFFER-COMPARE, I get the following error.

> WARNING: The USING phrase of the BUFFER-COMPARE statement only honors
>   fields in the source buffer. Ignoring 'cFieldsToCompare'. (5379)

Here is a code sample to clarify, I would like to only compare Field1, Field2, Field4 between `buf_target` and `buf_origin`. However, I can't simply write the fields down because they are provided and won't always be the same.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cChangedFields      AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFieldsToCompare    AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.

cFieldsToCompare = "Field1,Field2,Field4"

BUFFER-COMPARE buf_target 
USING cFieldsToCompare
TO buf_origin 
SAVE RESULT IN cChangedFields NO-ERROR.
```

Is there a syntaxe that allow `BUFFER-COMPARE` to receive fields to compare dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the BUFFER-COMPARE method of the Buffer handle:

```
BUFFER buf_target:BUFFER-COMPARE (BUFFER bug_origin:HANDLE, ?, cExceptFields, cFieldsToCompare) .
```